# Can't move instantiated prefub in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My prefub is sphere. The problem is that it doesn't move.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject sphereInstantiated;

    void Start()
    {
        sphereInstantiated = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Character");
        Instantiate(sphereInstantiated, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        sphereInstantiated.transform.position += Vector3.forward * 100 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

I tried to instantiate object by public variable, nothing changed.

Comment: No. Because youre moving the prefab not the instantated one you made from it.

Comment: The `Instantiate` method returns a reference to the spawned object. You should save it to a variable and use that instead of trying to modify the position of `sphereInstantiated`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved. Final code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SphereController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject sphere;
    private GameObject sphereInstantiated;

    void Start()
    {
        sphere = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Character");
        sphereInstantiated = Instantiate(sphere, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        sphereInstantiated.transform.position += Vector3.forward * 100 * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```